# Neo4j alternative for mysql views

Tags: mysql, neo4j

I need a help please, I'm new for Neo4j database, and actually I'm just started learning it 2 days ago. I've a task to migrate our mysql database to the neo4j database. I've created nodes and their relations, and I exported mysql tables to csv files and imported them to the neo4j. 
I've 2 questions regarding this:

1. I've some mysql views and I used to rely on them to get some real time statistics. I'm tryin since hrs to figure out a way to define something in new4j that alters the views structure. In my sql I used to select a specific row from the view and get its values. How could I do that now?
2. Is there a way that I can keep both mysql and neo4j running, and keep the neo4j synced with mysql? Like if I inserted data to mysql, is there a way to be synced automatically with neo4j?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly did you use the views for?

Comment: You might check out the apoc procedures that are able to pull data from relational databases, and have means to run queries periodically in the background, so you could sync data periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *views* in Neo4j - you'll need to create your queries around the nodes and relationships you're constructing. And nothing stops you from having additional relationships between nodes, to facilitate your queries.

Neo4j is its own databases, separate from any others (such as your MySQL instance). Any synchronization that needs to be done needs to happen within your app.